# Display text loop mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a problem. I need to display information in "description goes here" in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8vve.png

but, i need to take the description from another table

```
$newquery = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM init WHERE name='".$_SESSION['blabla']['user']."' ");
```

and there's the problem, if i put it in the last while it doesn't work. so i dont know how to do it.

---

```
    $query_check = mysql_query("SELECT PJ1,PJ2,PJ3,PJ4,PJ5,PJ6,PJ7,PJ8 FROM accounts WHERE name='".$_SESSION['blabla']['user']."' ");
    $query_personajes = mysql_query("SELECT PJ1,PJ2,PJ3,PJ4,PJ5,PJ6,PJ7,PJ8 FROM accounts WHERE name='".$_SESSION['blabla']['user']."' ");
    $query_check2 = mysql_query("SELECT PJ1 FROM accounts WHERE name='".$_SESSION['blabla']['user']."' ");

    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($query_check2)) {
        if($row2[0] == ""){ 
            echo "
        <div id=\"content-social\">
        <div id=\"content-normal-header\"></div>
        <div id=\"content-normal-summary\">
        <div class=\"text\" style=\"text-align:center; margin-left:0; padding-top: 10px;\">¡You dont have any character!</div>
        </div>
        <div id=\"content-normal-footer\"></div>
        </div>    
              ";
        }else{
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_check)) {
                $count = 0;
                if($row[0] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[1] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[2] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[3] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[4] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[5] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[6] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
                if($row[7] == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $count++;
                    }
            }
            $times = 0;

            while($columna=mysql_fetch_row($query_personajes)) {
                foreach ($columna as $dato){
                    $times++;
                    if($contador == $times-1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    else
                        {
**$chars = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM init WHERE Name='".$dato."' ");
while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($chars)) {**
                            echo "
        <div id=\"content-social\">
        <div id=\"content-normal-header\"></div>
        <div id=\"content-normal-summary\">
        <div class=\"avatar\"><img src=\""></img><span>".$dato."</span></div>
                            <div class=\"text\">Description goes here</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id=\"content-normal-footer\"></div>
                            <div id=\"content-normal-comments\"> Date: D: </div>
                            </div>

                            ";
        }     
              }

        }
        }
        }
        }
```

I think this what i was trying was impossible. I wrote another code an hour ago and it worked because i used another value from another table. So thank you all. It was just the query. Post edited with working code.

Comment: Could you indent your code? If you've got all those if statements, you might want to look at using a switch instead.

Comment: You have a missing backslash: `<img src=\"">` should be `<img src=\"\">`. Is that in the real code or a copying error? That's what caused my indentation to get messed up at the end -- the quotes aren't balanced.

Comment: I will but while may somebody help me? :D

Comment: The thing is, i need the way to display it, the errors like Barmar noticed before are correct in my code. So thank you but i just need the way to display it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).